# Unexpected error while activating windows 8: No DNS Server configured for local system

Tags: windows-8, dns, windows-activation

Below is a screenshot with error appeared after trying to activate windows 8. How can I fix this? Internet is working.

Once I will be able, I start and offer a bounty for the one who help me solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Error 0x8007267C activating windows 8: No DNS Server configured for local system

> **Resolution**
>
> Method 1:  Register a DNS server in the network properties and test
>   name resolution
>
> To resolve this problem client connectivity to a DNS server must be
>   resolved. The following steps may help to expose the problem
>
> 1. On the client getting the error, open a command prompt and run `IPCONFIG /all`
> 2. Verify the assigned IP address, subnet mask, DNS server and default gateway are set with the correct values for your environment.
> 3. Verify basic IP connectivity to the DNS Server using the PING command using the address of the DNS server from step 1.
>
>    ```
>    ping <DNS Server IP address>
>    ```
>
> If connectivity to the DNS server is failing then consider using the
>   following as a guide to troubleshoot further:
>
> [Troubleshooting TCP/IP
>   Problems](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727023.aspx)
>
> After resolving the connectivity issues to the DNS server, reattempt
>   activation using the following command from an Elevated Command prompt
>
> ```
> cscript \windows\system32\slmgr.vbs –ato
> ```
>
> Method 2:  Use a MAK (multiple activation key) and phone based
>   activation
>
> If you do not have a DNS server connected to the network, you can
>   switch to a MAK product key to activate your volume license
>   installation. If you are using MSDN media or TechNet media, you must
>   change the product key to the product key provided. The MSDN product
>   key or the TechNet product key for Windows Server 2008 or for Windows
>   Vista Enterprise is the MAK product key.
>
> Use the following command to change the product key to the MAK product
>   key:
>
> ```
> slmgr -ipk xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx
> ```
>
> Then, launch the phone activation wizard to complete the activation of
>   the machine
>
> ```
> slui 04
> ```

Source [Windows Activation fails with error code: 0x8007267C](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2009462)

Comment: `ping 192.168.0.1` was successful, so it means that server doesn't fail... right?

Comment: To be sure do `nslookup www.google.com`. What output do you get from this?

Comment: Shouldn't they just be able to throw in primary and secondary DNS servers manually by changing IP settings for the network they're connected to in settings?